# Django - static file issue

Tags: python, django

I don't understand why the image it doesn't shows. What could be the issue? My static-folder is positioned in my core_app as you can see in the picture but I'm working on my quiz_app folder. In my settings.py it seems everything ok, for the path to display the image I followed the documentation, I think the problem is where my folder is but I'm not sure. If I just put the image using css like " background-image: url("/static/img/CHALLENGE.png"); " it works but of course it's not what I'm trying to do. So I don't understand why the img src doesn't work.

[image: folder static]

quiz/quiz.html

```
    % extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title%}
      Quiz_page
    {% endblock %}

    {% block content %}

    {% load static %}

 <div class="card">

      <img src= "{% static '/static/img/CHALLENGE.png'%}" alt="" >
</div>
```

piattaforma/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for piattaforma project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '_j*f+(ceue_ff4hrgfk0l&r+)wrp@b8k2o4*snuenmuo$7yxib'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'accounts',
    'core',
    'quiz',
    'jobs',
    'emoji_picker',

]

REGISTRATION_DEFAULT_GROUP_NAME="Students"


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'piattaforma.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'accounts/templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'core/templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'quiz/templates'),
                  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'jobs/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'piattaforma.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/


STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL= '/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <img src= "{% static '/static/img/CHALLENGE.png'%}" alt="" >
```

change to

```
 <img src= "{% static 'img/CHALLENGE.png' %}" alt="" >
```